# Will making a variable volatile work if I take copy it to another variable and try to change that?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

I have an android Application object (although this is purely a java question I believe) as below

I wanted to understand if the way I have used volatile is correct, I have defined appData in Application as volatile, does that automatically guarantee that all the variables inside AppData object (each of them are complex objects like arrays , etc themselves) are also volatile or do I need to explicitly make them volatile like i have done

Morever, as I mention in the comment tagged QUESTION, does equating a new variable X to a volatile variable also make X volatile?

```
public class App extends Application{
    private volatile static AppData appData;

    public void fetchMePageInfo(long idOfUserIfNotForSelf) {

        RestService.getMePageInfo(new Callback<MePageInfo>() {          // RestService is just another class that calls Web server, and has static method getMepageInfo

            @Override
            public void success(MePageInfo newMePageInfo, Response response) {
                // for successful server request, store the newly fetched me page in array
                // and set ref to both self me page ref = me page to be displayed = new object,

                ArrayList<MePageInfo> mPageInfoList = appData.getMePageInfoList();      
                // QUESTION : AppData is volatile, but does that mean mPageInfoList is also threadsafe?

                MePageInfo selfRef = appData.getUserMePageInfo();
                if (selfRef != null) {
                    // if me page exists already, additionally remove the existing me page first
                    mPageInfoList.remove(selfRef);
                }
                mPageInfoList.add(newMePageInfo);

                appData.setUserMePageInfo(newMePageInfo);  // does not automatically call change listeners

            }


        });
    }




}


public class AppData {

    /**
    this has the MePageInfo objects of the various other users that the logged in user might go to 
     for quick fetch, instead of calling server each time
    **/
    volatile ArrayList<MePageInfo> mePageInfoList = new ArrayList<MePageInfo>();

    // region self Me page info data
    /**
     * the MePageInfo for the logged in user, this is null initially and is filled by FetchGenericMePageInfo for the user
     */

    volatile MePageInfo userMePageInfo = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Volatile and thread-safe are not the same thing. `volatile` guarantees you that

1. A write to a `volatile` variable and a subsequent read of this variable establishes a happens-before relationship between two threads.
2. All read and writes of this particular variable are atomic.

That's all what it does. So if you assign a value of a `volatile` variable to another one, it does not make it `volatile`. The concept of thread safety is more complex and the fact that a variable is `volatile` does not mean that even this variable itself is thread-safe.

Comment: For more info, look at these example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Being "volatile" is a property of a variable, not a property of the object that it refers to.  So (assuming we're talking about reference variables here, not primitives), marking a variable "volatile" does not make an object thread-safe.  And it's possible that you'll have a volatile variable and a non-volatile variable that both refer to the same object.

So when you mark a reference variable as "volatile", you're saying that other threads may make the variable refer to a *different object*.  You're not saying that other threads may mutate the object that it refers to.

So to answer your first question, the volatility of fields within an object is completely independent of the volatility of any variable that refers to the object.  And to answer your second question, a variable can't somehow become volatile by referring to a volatile object.

Answer (score 0):

> does that automatically guarantee that all the variables inside AppData object (each of them are complex objects like arrays , etc themselves)

No.  Doing something like:

```
appData = new AppData();
appData.mePageInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Is not thread-safe.  The write to `mePageInfoList` can be read out of order. So to answer your question, there is no garuantee about when the write to the fields inside `AppData` will be read.

> do I need to explicitly make them volatile like i have done

Yes, but even then you're not necessarily safe.  For instance `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe, so assigning to `mePageInfoList` will be thread-safe but any later mutation of the collection will be at risk.

> does equating a new variable X to a volatile variable also make X volatile?

Not exactly sure what you are asking, can you give an example?